# org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: Open quote is expected for attribute "component" associated with an element type "Route"

Tags: reactjs, spring-boot, sax

I am developing a React.js +Spring boot app and I am getting this error -

**"org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: Open quote is expected for attribute
component" associated with an  element type  "Route".**

here is the piece of code which is giving me problem -

```
ReactDOM.render(
  <Router>
        <Route path="/" component={App}>
            <IndexRoute component={Home}/>
            <Route path="stuff" component={Stuff} />
             <Route path="contact" component={Contact} />
        </Route>
 </Router>,  Destination
);
```

Answer (score 0):

You have full description of error. You use SAX parser to parse react code. component={App} this is not valid XML . All attributes should be in quotes in XML.

To help you need to know what you whant at the end of the day.